# Error on HQL Query distinct count of child collections (in elements error)

Tags: nhibernate, hql, distinct

First of all, please forgive me for my vocabulary is a little limited with NHibernate so I might call something the wrong thing...here is my question:

Result I am looking for is a count of distinct students for a course. I have three classes: 
Courses, Students, CourseDates. 
Courses contains a HasMany relationship with CourseDates.
CourseDates is a collection of dates on which each class has occurred and contains a HasAndBelongsToMany relationship with the Students class.

What I need to do is a get a distinct count of the Students from all the dates a course has occurred. Here is an example of a SQL statement that I want to replicate. The result is a number (long). This specific example produces the result: 5

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Literacy_Course_DatesStudents.IDStudent) AS StudentCount FROM
Literacy_Course_DatesStudents INNER JOIN Literacy_Course_Dates ON Literacy_Course_DatesStudents.IDDate = Literacy_Course_Dates.IDDate WHERE     (Literacy_Course_Dates.IDCourse = 28)`

Below is the query written from within a new class that I created specifically for this report...but I keep getting an error: Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.MissingTokenException' was thrown. Usually I thought this error was thrown when I didn't have CourseEnrolledCount class imported into the other classes but I have done that.

```
Dim q As Castle.ActiveRecord.Queries.SimpleQuery(Of CourseEnrolledCount)
q = New Castle.ActiveRecord.Queries.SimpleQuery(Of CourseEnrolledCount)(GetType(Literacy.Courses.CourseDates), "select new CourseEnrolledCount(Count(Distinct o.IDStudent in elements(t.Students) as o)) from CourseDates t Where t.Course.IDCourse = :courseid")
```

Let me know if I need to provide additional information. I hope I am being clear in my question. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a HQL query that does what you want:

```
select count(disctinct student.id) from Course course
inner join course.courseDates courseDate
inner join courseDate.students student
where course.id = :courseId
```

I'll let you substitute the real names of the associations.

You could even make it shorter (and more similar to your SQL query) by avoiding the join on the course:

```
select count(disctinct student.id) from CourseDate courseDate
inner join courseDate.students student
where courseDate.course.id = :courseId
```

Comment: YAY! These both worked perfectly! I opted for the shorter one. Thank you so very much! I was fighting with this for two days solid.